# How do you collapse a key-value data stack back onto itself to keep the ID's sequential?

Tags: sql, data-structures, sqlite

So here is the data structure. It's simplistic, but there's a catch.

```
INT id, TEXT subject, TEXT response
```

Basically, it's going to be populated with simple data entries. However, they need to support removal. The catch is, the ID numbers always have to be sequential. eg, 1-100 not skipping around like 1-4,6-12,14-100 because 5 and 13 were deleted.

What I'm asking is, basically, **how do you collapse a key-value data stack back onto itself to keep the ID's sequential?**

Comment: Why is sequential IDs a requirement?

Comment: can the IDs change? if so maybe ID shouldn't be part of your data structure and instead use row_number() for whatever you're using ID for now.

Answer (score 0):

If this was actually a requirement (and something smells fishy about that), I would probably accomplish it with an ON DELETE trigger.

In this trigger, whenever a delete occurred, I would immediately fetch the row corresponding to the current **max(id)** in the table, and if **max(id)** is greater than the id of the row you just deleted*, I'd do an update on the existing row's ID to match the ID of the row just deleted.

*The reason to check that **max(id)** is greater than the id of the row you just deleted, is to make sure you don't do the update in the case where you just deleted the max row.

Now, I don't know if sqlite even supports triggers. If it doesn't, you'll have to implement this same logic in your client code.

Of course this means your ids will fluctuate wildly... which in most applications would be far more problematic than having non-sequential IDs. So I'm still left wondering why you think you need sequential IDs.